# What is a Hot & Cold Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>*This puzzle is based on and inspired by the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by JLee that have grown into Word™, [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2), and [Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Hot & Cold Word™.

This is a list of Hot & Cold Words™ and Not Hot & Cold Words™.

| Hot & Cold Word™ | Not Hot & Cold Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| Fox | Bear |
| Agreement | Disagreement |
| Pristine | Dirty |
| Asteroidea | Polychaeta |
| Investigator | Police |
| Dawn | Dusk |
| Conversation | Fight |
| Assistance | Hinderance |

CSV:

```
Hot & Cold Word™,Not Hot & Cold Word™
Fox,Bear
Agreement,Disagreement
Pristine,Dirty
Asteroidea,Polychaeta
Investigator,Police
Dawn,Dusk
Conversation,Fight
Assistance,Hinderance
```

Hint #1:

> It will be harder to solve this puzzle in the future (e.g. 1 month from now).

Hint #2:

> All hot & cold words are synonyms of words in a specific collection.
>  Most people don't know this collection even exists, but most people who read this probably *do* know it exists :)

Comment: Just so you know in advance, I will not edit hints into this question for 7 days for reasons obvious to some. I might answer questions posted as comments.

Comment: I keep returning to this (yes, even today... sorry family...) and the fact the first word is FOX and there are specifically 8 entries (and the hint seems to confirm a theme) means my thinking has been all one way for a while... I just can't connect all the dots! (Or work out how the title would be relevant...) Just wanted to give you some evidence that people are actually trying to solve this :)

Comment: I've tried connections to things that change over time such as constellations, heating/melting of elements, dates as well as converting to a few different things but not seeing a pattern or link anywhere. Unsure of whether the hint is literal or not, would the question be even harder the more time that passes or is it a fixed difficulty increase?

Comment: "It will be harder to solve this puzzle in the future (e.g. 1 month from now)." well, look at the time now XD

Comment: Maybe another hind because its been 3 months from the date posted

Comment: @LukasRotter Can we please have another hint now you're back? My train of thought on this has become so obscure that I don't know what I'm thinking any more and this tab has been open for like 6 months.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Hot & Cold Word™ is one of the

> hats from the [Winter Bash 2021 Hat List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list)

Fitting ones are

> Fox - Kitsune
>  Agreement - Consensus
>  Pristine - Spotless
>  Asteroidea - Starfish
>  Investigator - Detective
>  Dawn - Sunrise
>  Conversation - Dialogue
>  Assistance - Helping hand

Comment: Ah, well recalled/researched! Funny how I was in 'the right area' in two different ways yet still miles away... Good to be able to put this one to rest at last :)

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Okay, I've been thinking about this one for a while, and I have something that I believe works for at least 7/8 words (I can't pin down the other) and the timing of the initial puzzle - something that was hinted at as being relevant. I believe that 'Fox', 'Pristine', 'Asteroidea' and 'Dawn' in particular work *incredibly* well under this theory, so let's put this out there as a possibility...</sup>

I think a Hot & Cold Word might be:

> a word with a **synonym related to Christmas**. The reason the OP hinted 'It will be harder to solve this puzzle in the future' would therefore be that Christmas-related words would be more likely to come to mind during the festive season (when this question was posted).
>
>  Furthermore, these words would be called 'Hot & Cold Words' because depending on the *hemisphere* in which you celebrate the occasion it will fall either in summer (southern) or winter (northern), so the weather might be hot or cold!

The pattern among the given words would look like this:

> Fox = **VIXEN**, one of Santa's reindeer.
>
>  Agreement = **[RECONCILIATION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconciliation_(theology))** - in Christianity, an element of salvation brought about by the events of Jesus' birth, life and death. Alternatively, **PEACE** and **HARMONY** are nice fits here too.
>
>  Pristine = **IMMACULATE** - the '[Immaculate Conception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immaculate_Conception)' of the Virgin Mary.
>
>  [Asteroidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfish) = **STAR**, like the one which guided the Magi to Bethlehem.
>
>  Investigator = *I am yet to decide on a truly appropriate synonym here - possibly something connected to the Magi?*
>
>  Dawn = **ADVENT**, the period leading up to Christmas.
>
>  Conversation = **COMMUNION** - another Christian concept relating to remembering the life of Jesus.
>
>  Assistance = **SERVICE** - many religious *services* are held in the Christmas period.

The opposing words listed have little or no connection to this theme and have been chosen just for the similarity to the words in the left-hand column (although I appreciate that 'child-*bear*ing' plays a pretty major part!).

Answer (score 0):

A Hot & Cold word is

> a word that relates to the name of a spacecraft with connections to the International Space Station

> Fox - **KITSUNE** (Japanese for Fox) nanosatellite - Launched from the ISS
>
>  Agreement - **Axiom** (universal truth, everyone in agreement) Space Station -  First commercial destination module on the International Space Station (maybe)
>
>  Pristine - **Tiangong** - Translates to "Heaven's Palace" or "Celestial Palace" - The Chinese equivelant of the ISS
>
>  Asteroidea - **Zvezda** (star) (ISS module)
>
>  Investigator -  **Poisk** (search) (ISS module)
>
>  Dawn - **Zarya** (Dawn) (ISS module)
>
>  Conversation - **Project Mercury** - Mercury (God of communication) - Formed the basis for long term stays in space
>
>  Assistance - **TKS** (Transport Supply Spacecraft) - Formed the basis of the Zarya ISS module

Edit: I hadn't refreshed, I was miles off.